# Android XML comments with double dashes

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, layout

I just obtained a debug Google Maps API key for my new MacBook, and Google spit back a key with double dashes ("--") in it.  I normally put all of our debug keys in comments so that others can store their keys in the source and copy/pasta as necessary.  Out of convenience for the team, really.

The compiler throws a fit when you have these double dashes in comments.  Is there a way to escape or otherwise encode my key so I can store it in a comment?

Example:

> ```
>     <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
>     android:id="@+id/mapview_map"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>       android:apiKey="ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF0123456789--123456789" />
>     <!--  android:apiKey="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" />  CERT KEY --> 
>     <!--  android:apiKey="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />  Sally debug Key -->
>     <!--  android:apiKey="ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF0123456789--123456789" />  Joe debug key -->
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the XML standard, no: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments

I'd recommend just picking another character not in 0-9,A-F that everyone will understand means dash, like an underscore.  -- inside of an XML comment invalidates the XML, and there's no way around it.

Comment: If there's no other way, I'll have to do this.  I was hoping for some sort of escaped format I could use to avoid it though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CDATA section. E.g. instead of

```
<!--  android:apiKey="ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF0123456789--123456789" />  Joe debug key -->
```

use

```
<![CDATA[
android:apiKey="ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF0123456789--123456789" />  Joe debug key
]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a processing instruction instead of a comment. That will work until you find a key with "?>" in it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by a "processing instruction" inside of XML.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: OK, after a little digging it appears these "processing instructions" cannot be placed in the XML layout files.  Or at least I couldn't get it to work :-(